# powershell - extract file type from zip

Tags: powershell, zip

I have a zipfile with a random filename that is enclosed within a randomly-named zipfile. I am refining the following sample code:

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
 $zip = $shell.NameSpace(“C:\howtogeeksite.zip”)
foreach($item in $zip.items())
 {
 $shell.Namespace(“C:\temp\howtogeek”).copyhere($item)
 }
```

The outer zipfile contains a few hundred files I don't need plus this one zipfile inside it- How do I refine the above source code to only grab the inner zip file (It could just extract all files from the outer zipfile whose extension is .zip)... Please advise the easiest way to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: you have to know the name or the pattern for the name in order to identify it and extract it.  Do you have that name or pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the contents checking if the file extension of each item is ".zip" before extracting.  Something like this should work:

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace(“C:\howtogeeksite.zip”)

foreach($item in $zip.items()){

    if([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($item.Path) -eq ".zip"){

        $shell.Namespace(“C:\temp\howtogeek”).copyhere($item)

    }

}
```